# two pointer error: whenever i use while(left<=right) it gives an error, but when i remove the equal sign it works fine

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, stdvector, undefined-behavior

```
vector<int> v{-10,-7,-3,2,5,6}, v1(6);
    int left = 0;
    int right = 5;
    int i=0;
    while (left<=right){
        if (abs(v[left])>abs(v[right])){
            v1[i]=v[left]*v[left];
            left++;
        }
        else if (abs(v[left])<abs(v[right])){
            v1[i]=v[right]*v[right];
            right--;
        }
         else if (abs(v[left])==abs(v[right])){
             v1[i]=v[right]*v[right];
         }
        i++;
    }
    reverse(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    for (int ele:v1)
    {
        cout<<ele<<" ";
    }
```

whenever i use (left<=right) it gives an error, but when i remove the equal sign it works fine

Comment: `while (left<=right)` runs 7 times (before crashing), so the last `v[i]` accesses out of bounds. `while (left<right)` runs 6 times and therefore does not have that problem.

Comment: The first line in the body of the while, `if (i > 5) throw "oops";`

Answer (score 0):

Due to this else statement

```
 else if (abs(v[left])==abs(v[right])){
     v1[i]=v[right]*v[right];
 }
```

you can get an infinite loop when `left` is equal to `right` because neither `left` nor `right` is changed. On the other hand, the variable `i` is incremented

```
i++;
```

and as a result there will be an access to memory outside the vector `v1`.

Answer (score 0):

If `left == right` your cycle become endless. And you increment `i` every time, so you will call `v1[i]=v[right]*v[right];`, where `i` more than 5, and receive SEGFAULT